# scraping a fake <a> with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python, and I'm using BeautifullSoup to scrape data from an html page.

So far, everything fine. But some links are weird, and perhaps the purpose is not to be scraped.
This page : https://francechansons.net/alain-souchon-liste-de-chansons/ has a list of links, with href being themselves links, instead of url.
My current code is :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html_page = urlopen('https://francechansons.net/alain-souchon-liste-de-chansons/')
soup = bs(html_page, 'lxml')

entry_content_div=soup.find("div", class_="entry-content") 
ul = entry_content_div.find("ul")
li = ul.find('li')
children = li.findChildren("a")
for child in children:
    print(child)
```

I get

```
 <a href="alain_souchon-18_ans_que_j_t_ai_a_l_oeil">18 ans que j’t’ai à l’œil</a>
```

instead of :

```
<a href="https://francechansons.net/alain_souchon-18_ans_que_j_t_ai_a_l_oeil/">18 ans que j’t’ai à l’œil</a>'
```

Hope someone understands this convoluted message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the `href` with a base url like this:

```
baseUrl = 'https://francechansons.net/'
    for child in children:
        print(baseUrl+child['href'])
```

But check if there is already an `http` in the `href`:

```
if 'http' in child['href']:
    print(child['href'])
else:
    print(baseUrl+child['href'])
```

**Example**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html_page = urlopen('https://francechansons.net/alain-souchon-liste-de-chansons/')
soup = bs(html_page, 'lxml')

entry_content_div=soup.find("div", class_="entry-content") 
ul = entry_content_div.find("ul")
li = ul.find('li')
children = li.findChildren("a")
baseUrl = 'https://francechansons.net/'
for child in children:
    if 'http' in child['href']:
        print(child['href'])
    else:
        print(baseUrl+child['href'])
```

**Output**

https://francechansons.net/alain_souchon-18_ans_que_j_t_ai_a_l_oeil

Comment: Ok than you ! that is exactly what I was searching for